# Can Stanford Parser ignore case?

Tags: stanford-nlp, stanford-parser

I've been playing with http://corenlp.run/ and noticed that it is case sensitive. 
For example, it tags "i" as FW versus "I" as PRP.
Can I train it to ignore case? More generally, how do I go about training it for non-well formed sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CorenNLP has case insensitive models that you can use for English only. They call them [caseless models](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/caseless.html). Read the warning there if you use version 3.6.0

A couple of points mentioned in the link:

1. You can fix the case of letters in your text and use the normal models. You may use `TrueCaseAnnotator` for that.
2. To train your own case insensitive models with CoreNLP you can specify a token preprocessor that ignores case

   ```
   wordFunction = edu.stanford.nlp.process.LowercaseFunction
   ```